# Can't use Linux wc on one-line file

Tags: linux, command, diff, wc

I have a one-line file with no newline character at the end of the line. When i run the following:

```
diff oneline-file.txt any-file.txt | wc -c
```

I get:

```
Warning: missing newline character in oneline-file.txt
```

Why is this an error? How can i fix it? I could do this first:

```
echo "\n" >> oneline-file.txt
```

I'd rather do something that does not change the file. Thx.

Comment: It's just a warning, it doesn't affect the result.

Comment: What version of `diff` is this? I don't get that warning, but the output has `\ No newline at end of file`.

Comment: `echo "\n"` won't echo a newline, it will echo that literal string.

Comment: what distro are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Barmar. This steered me in the right direction. Here's what I used:

```
diff <(sed 's/$/\n/g' oneline-file.txt) <(cat any-file.txt) | wc -c
```

Answer (score -1):

You could pipe the result of your `echo` into `diff`, replacing the file name as an argument to `diff` with `-` (telling it to get that input from stdin).

Answer (score -1):

You can use process substitution to echo the newline after the file:

```
diff <(cat oneline-file.txt; echo "") any-file.txt | wc -c
```